# Renderizar Html

Tags: javascript, json, react, cms, react-hooks

Estou consumindo um json onde tenho uma chave com o valor de uma tag html:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
export const CardHome = () => {

  const [recebeDados, setRecebeDados] = useState([
    {
      jsonApi: {
        atrr: [
          {value:"<h1>Hello world</h1><p>Aqui eu renderizo um texto</p>"},
          {value:"<h1>Hello</h1><p>Aqui eu renderizo um texto SEGUNDO</p>"},
          {value:"<h1>Hello bRAZIL</h1><p>Aqui eu renderizo um TERCEIRO</p>"},
        ]
      }
    }
  ])

  return(
    <>
    {recebeDados.map((e,i) => (
      <ul key={i}>
        <li>{e.value}</li>
      </ul>
    ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Eu gostaria de renderizar as informações sem as tags HTML, será que é possível?

Comment: veja se te ajuda https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-string-exercise-35.php "strip_html" https://codepen.io/flourigh/pen/eYmYjKW

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso sem HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Exemplo: `value.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');`

Aqui ele está apagando os símbolos "<" e ">" e tudo que está entre eles (substituindo os símbolos por nada) usando RegEx (regular expressions).